Unity XR Toolkit make a spawned object interactable
i have a c# script that generates multiple objects and controls their positions based on some custom physics
i want the generated objects to be intractable in the oculus headset using the controller,
i want the user to be able to grab the object and play with it. also i want to detect when multiple objects are grabbed and track the positions of the objects.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class Node
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
    public float mass = 1;
    public float spring_constant = 1;
    public Node[] connections;
    public Node(float x, float y, float z, Node[] connections)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.connections = connections;
    }
}


public class spawn_graph : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Node[] nodes = new Node[10];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // add 10 random nodes at random positions
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            nodes[i] = new Node((float)Random.Range(0, 10), (float)Random.Range(0, 10), (float)Random.Range(0, 10), null);
        }

        

        // spawn the nodes as simple spheres
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            GameObject node = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            node.transform.position = new Vector3(nodes[i].x, nodes[i].y, nodes[i].z);
            
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // apply repulsion between nodes using nodes.length
        // does some physics that change the positions of the objects

        
        
    }
}


